# How to work with arrays and display them in a MsgBox VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I need to write a sub that take a single argument from an input box that searches a stock price in a list. The sub searches down the list of prices from "B3:B20" and when it finds the first price that exceeds this price it displays the date which is displays in the column next to it in column A in a msgbox. This is the code I have so far but I am having trouble figuring out how to display the corresponding data for the price found:(I believe the problem has to do with the array created)

```
Sub RecordHigh1()
Dim searchPrice As Currency
Dim rng As Range
Dim date1() As String
Dim price() As String
Dim nDates As Integer
Dim i As Integer



With wsData.Range("A3")
nDates = Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown).Value)
ReDim date1(1 To nDates)
ReDim price(1 To nDates)
For i = 1 To nDates
    date1(i) = .Offset(i, 0).Value
    price(i) = .Offset(i, 1).Value
Next
End With


searchPrice = InputBox("Enter a Price")
Set rng = Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown).Address)

For Each cell In rng
If cell.Value > searchPrice Then
MsgBox "The first date WalTech stock price exceeded " & searchPrice & " was & date(i) =.Offset(i, 0).Value & "
Else
MsgBox "WalTech stock has not exceeded this price"
End If
Next



End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing a  `"`  so  `searchPrice & " was & date(i)`  should be  `searchPrice & " was " & date(i)`  And the  ampersand and double quote at the end needs to be removed.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah the code still wont work

Comment: @th65 - which line does the code break on?

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub RecordHigh1()
Dim searchPrice As Currency
Dim rng As Range
Dim date1() As String
Dim price() As String
Dim nDates As Long
Dim i As Long '<~~ always better to use Long type instead of integer

Dim cell As Range


'With wsData.Range("A3")'<~~ wsData is not defined. or is it a Public variable?
With ActiveSheet.Range("A3") '<~~ otherwise set it to a specific sheet: With Worksheets("MySheet").Range("A3")
    nDates = .Range(.Cells, .Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    ReDim date1(1 To nDates)
    ReDim price(1 To nDates)
    With .Range("A3")
        For i = 1 To nDates
            date1(i) = .Offset(i, 0).Value
            price(i) = .Offset(i, 1).Value
        Next i '<~~ always better to type the variable you want to iterate on
    End With
End With


searchPrice = InputBox("Enter a Price")
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B3", ActiveSheet.Range("B3").End(xlDown).Address)'<~~ better to add sheet reference (ActiveSheet or Worksheets("MySheet") or wsData, this latter once you define it) 

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value > searchPrice Then
        MsgBox "The first date WalTech stock price exceeded " & searchPrice & " was " & cell.Offset(, -1)
    Else
        MsgBox "WalTech stock has not exceeded this price"
    End If
Next cell '<~~ always better to type the variable you want to iterate on

End Sub
```